# Black background appears on the last scene

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have a problem, once the hot air balloon reaches the ground, a black background appears.

[image]

```
// a switch case based on state with appropriate calls
switch (state) {
// scene 1
case 1:     
    drawBackground1(); // the first background to appear
    drawSlogan1(); // display the first slogan
    break;
// scene 2
case 2:     
    drawBackground2(); // the second background to appear
    drawSlogan2(); // display the second slogan
    break;
// scene 3
case 3:     
    drawBackground1(); // the third background to appear
    drawSlogan3(); // display the last slogan
    break;
}
```

I am showing this code here is because this is the only code I have changed, that made the black background appear.

[Click here to see the full code](http://cpp.sh/66kbs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the balloon reaches the final position, then `state` is 0. You have to draw the background if `state == 0`, too:

```cpp
switch (state) {
case 0: 
    drawBackground1(); // the third background to appear
    break;
case 1:     
    drawBackground1(); // the first background to appear
    drawSlogan1(); // display the first slogan
    break;
case 2:     
    drawBackground2(); // the second background to appear
    drawSlogan2(); // display the second slogan
    break;
case 3:     
    drawBackground1(); // the third background to appear
    drawSlogan3(); // display the last slogan
    break;
}
```